# PHP file returns the entire file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Just learning php. I am trying to connect PHP with Javascript through AJAX call.
My javascript file looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"test.php",
    success:function(data) {
        console.log(data); // to check response
    }
});
```

and my php file looks like:

```
<?php
  include('example.php');
  header("Content-type: text/javascript");

  $key = '4e899892ede0f86b7cb65f974cede5ff';
  $latitude = $_GET['latitude'];
  $longitude = $_GET['longitude'];
  $timestamp = $_GET['timestamp'];

  $weather = new WeatherAPIConnector('4e899892ede0f86b7cb65f974cede5ff');
  $condition = $weather->getCurrentForecast($latitude,$longitude,$timestamp);
  echo $condition;

  $conditi = array();
  $conditi = $weather->getTodaysTemp($latitude,$longitude);
  echo $conditi;
?>
```

The console shows the entire php file(console.log(data)):
[image]

Please let me know how to get the value of $conditi alone

Comment: You have to either enable a php module inside your http server or configure it to route requests to php files through to either `cgi` script execution or a `fastcgi` server. How to do that obviously depends on the http server you use and the operating system you build on.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by your words

> Just learning php.

I believe you haven't setup a php webserver yet. To use PHP you need to do one of the following:

1. Setup a web server - you can use software such as XAMP.
2. Use free / paid Webhosting such as HostGator or any other webhosting provider. and upload your php file there.
3. Use http://phptester.net/.

And while you are at it, can you post the URL on your address bar?

Answer (score 0):

Check you web server configuration. It looks like the php is not executed but delivered as static content. 
Try to open it directly in the browser. Does it also show the php source code?

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same issue, thinking I coded something wrong.

**Solution:**

In CentOS7 for PHP7.2

- sudo yum-config-manager --enable remi-php72
- sudo yum install php php-common php-opcache php-mcrypt php-cli php-gd php-curl php-mysqlnd

The one enabling you to cURL data between your FRONT-SERVERS is the second line.

Each PHP7.x version has it own modules ...

Read this article, this is where I found the solution. 
https://linuxize.com/post/install-php-7-on-centos-7/

You can find the same php-modules in different distros, just need to research.